# Date Auto format with javaScript

Tags: javascript

how to make date Auto Format in input textbox with javascript

when input `yyyyMMdd` format in textbox, that will automatically change to `yyyy/MM/dd` format

for example:
if your type `20120427`, that will change to `2012/04/27`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this javaScript Function and Call it from  `onChange` event of your textbox

```
function dateFormat(el){
    value = el.value;       
    el.value = value.replace(/^([\d]{4})([\d]{2})([\d]{2})$/,"$1/$2/$3");        
}
```

Comment: This is great, but allows for dates like 0000/00/00, and 9999/99/99 which are invalid dates.

Answer (score -2):

First, you need to write a function to do the convert,

```
function convert(original){};
```

then listen to `onkeyup` evnets, and pass the value of the input to the convert function, set the input's value to its result