# Date Input Auto Format AND Prevent Alphabetic Characters

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a requirement for an html form with two different parts. The first is for a user to enter their date of birth in an input that will automatically add slashes as they type and prevent them from entering alphabetic characters at the same time. I've been able to work out the auto format requirement. To solve the second part I've been researching regular expressions, but can find anything that doesn't break the auto format at the same time. Here's my html:

```
<label for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth </label>
<input type="text"  name="dob" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" id="dob" pattern="^\\s*($1)\\W*($2)?\\W*($3)?([0-9]*).*" maxlength="10" class="validate"/>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
var format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
     var match = new RegExp(format
         .replace(/(\w+)\W(\w+)\W(\w+)/, "^\\s*($1)\\W*($2)?\\W*($3)?([0-9]*).*")
         .replace(/m|d|y/g, "\\d"));
     var replace = "$1/$2/$3$4"
         .replace(/\//g, format.match(/\W/));

     function doFormat(target)
     {
         target.value = target.value
             .replace(/(^|\W)(?=\d\W)/g, "$10")   // padding
             .replace(match, replace)             // fields
             .replace(/(\W)+/g, "$1");            // remove repeats
     }

     $("input[name='dob']:first").keyup(function(e) {
        if(!e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode > 46))
           doFormat(e.target)
     });
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4r15f951/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Auto format with javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346522/date-auto-format-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You can do it using jquery masking function.

You need remove your pattern from html input and the function is not required.
Instead You can use

```
<label for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth </label>
<input type="text"  name="dob" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" id="dob"  maxlength="10" class="validate"/>
```

Jquery

```
  $('.validate').mask("99/99/9999");
     $('.validate').change(function(){

    if($(this).val().substring(0,2) > 12 || $(this).val().substring(0,2) == "00") {
     alert("Iregular Month Format");
     return false;
    }
     if($(this).val().substring(3,5) > 31 || $(this).val().substring(0,2) == "00") {
     alert("Iregular Date Format");
     return false;
    }
      });
```

Add this to your script
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js

OnKeypress itself slashes appear automatically and entry of alphabets is restricted.

Here is my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0rw8rddf/

Comment: This is really helpful. I imagine I can set further parameters to throw an error if an individual is under 18?